Projective transform is not unique?
I'm currently preparing for my geometry exam and I stumbled upon this projective geometry exercise:

Consider the projective space $P^2_{\mathbb{Q}}$.
Let $r$ be the line of cartesian equations $y + z = 0$ and let $A := [1: -1: 0], B := [-1: 1: 1], C := [0: 1: 0], D := [1: 0: 1]$
Let $f: P^2_{\mathbb{Q}} \to P^2_{\mathbb{Q}}$ be a projective transform s.t. $f(A) = A, f(B) = B, f(r) = r, f(C) = D$ and prove that it is unique.

Let $s := L(A, B)$, we know that, because $f$ fixes $A, B$, then $f(s) = s$.
Let $P := s \cap r = [1: -1: 1]$, then we have that
$f(P) = f(s \cap r) \subseteq f(s) \cap f(r) = s \cap r = P$
So we have 4 points in general position $A, B, C, P$ which are sent to the points $A, B, D, P$, which are still in general position. As such we know that $f$ must be unique.
Now, I was trying to define the matrix of my transform. This is where I raised my doubts.
Consider the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2&1&0\\-1&0&0\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$
This matrix sends $(1, -1, 0)$ to $(1, -1, 0)$, $(-1, 1, 1)$ to $(-1, 1, 1)$, $(0, 1, 0)$ to $(1, 0, 1)$ and $(1, -1, 1)$ to $(1, -1, 1)$
Now consider the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&0\\-1&0&0\\-1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$
This matrix maps $(1, -1, 0) \to (1, -1, 0), (-1, 1, 1) \to (-1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0) \to (-1, 0, -1), (1, -1, 1) \to (1, -1, 1)$
Define $T_1, T_2$ as the projective transform associated to, respectively, the first and the second matrix.
We then have $T_1(A) = A, T_1(B) = B, T_1(C) = D, T_1(P) = P$
and $T_2(A) = A, T_2(B) = B, T_2(C) = [-1: 0: -1] = [1: 0: 1] = D, T_2(P) = P$
Therefore one must have $T_1 = T_2 = f$ for the same uniqueness theorem used before.
This is where my doubt raises. To me, because the two matrices aren't similar, we should have $T_1 \neq T_2$, contradicting the theorem. Where is my reasoning incorrect?

You wrote that the points $A, B, C, P$ are in general position, but how is this possibile if you construct the point $P$ in such a way $P$ lies on the line passing by $A$ and $B$?
Indeed, $2A+B=P$, so that $A, B, P$ are not a basis of $\mathbb R^3$ and then it is not true $A, B, C, P$ are in general position. This is explaining why you obtained more than one projective transformation satisfying our requirements (note also that the second matrix that you gave is not sending $r$ to itself, but only $P$ to $P$).
Instead of looking to the map $f$, maybe it can be useful to use the duality. The dual map of $f$ is sending the lines $L(A,B)$ and $r$ to themselves, and the lines $L(A,C)$ and $L(B,C)$ to $L(A,D)$ and $L(B,D)$ respectively.
The line $L(A,B)$ has equation $x+y=0$, so that the dual map of $f$ is fixing the vector $(1,1,0)$. The line $L(A, C)$ has equation $z=0$ and $L(B,C)$ has equation $x+z=0$. Finally, $L(A,D)$ has equation $x+y-z=0$ and $L(B,D)$ has equation $x+2y-z=0$.
Hence the dual map of $f$ has to send $(1,1,0)\mapsto (1,1,0)=(-1,-1,0)$, $(0,1,1)=(0,-1,-1)\mapsto (0,1,1)$, $(0,0,1)=(0,0,2)\mapsto (1,1,-1)=2(1,1,-1)$, and $(1,0,1)\mapsto (1,2,-1)$. Since the dual map of $f$ is sending a projective basis
$$\{(1,1,0),(0,-1,-1),(0,0,2),(1,0,1) \} $$
to a projective basis
$$\{(-1,-1,0),(0,1,1), 2(1,1,-1), (1,2,-1)\} $$
then it is unique, and so the map $f$ is unique too. In particular, we can compute a matrix $M$ defining the dual map as follows:
$$ M=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 &2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Thus the map $f$ is induced by the linear map given by the inverse of the transpose of $M$:
$$(M^t)^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & -2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}-2 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
that it is a matrix similar to your beginning matrix up to the multiplicative constant $-1$.
So the map $f$ is unique and it is given by your beginning matrix.
